# double and decimal not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to set a price either a double or decimal.
I get this error and I have tried all I know.

[image]

Model:

```
public double price { get; set; }
```

Controller create:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,farmID,productID,price, URL")] ProductFarm productFarm) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            db.farmProducts.Add(productFarm);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.farmID = new SelectList(db.farms.OrderBy(x => x.farmName), "farmID", "farmName", productFarm.farmID);
        ViewBag.productID = new SelectList(db.products.OrderBy(x => x.productName), "productID", "productName", productFarm.productID);
        return View(productFarm);
    }
```

Edit - added view code:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: is your server on a locale that uses comma as decimal separator, instead of dot?

Comment: You should always use _decimal_ for amounts.

Comment: show us ur view code for price field. Must be a type error

Comment: What the comma and dot.. The server is from Denmark so i'ts a comma.. Can I get a hint on how to fix that?

Comment: @WannaBeACoder jquery is responsible , use https://github.com/jquery/globalize to fix that

Comment: Cool! Do I need to anything else then install the nuget and refer to it in my layout page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is basically a locale issue. You have to set which locale you want to target to. By default the MVC scaffolding will default to your PC's culture.

You can set culture in your web.config

```
<system.web>
<globalization culture ="en-US" />
</system.web>
```

Since the issue is from the jquery validate plugin you can install jquery.validate.globalize

```
Install-Package jQuery.Validation.Globalize
```

Show's you how to use it https://johnnyreilly.github.io/jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive.Native/AdvancedDemo/Globalize.html

Or,

You can extend your jquery.validate plugin yourself http://www.cedricascoop.be/blog/2011/10/22/mvc-3-problems-validating-a-decimal/

```
number: function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value); //dot separated
        return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)(?:,\d+)?$/.test(value); //comma separated
    }
```

above code is from jquery.validate.js around line 1050 you can see the validation.Don't be confused I added the second return. I switched the return statement around. One return validates for dot another for comma.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't get that to work.. I have followed to link and stil not working :/

Comment: Put this in your web.config file <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US"/>
<system.web>

Comment: It has to be a locale error. Since you said something about denmark. I think your locale is on Denmark settings. Otherwise there is nothing wrong with your code.