# Decimal not recognized ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to insert a decimal number in one form but with no success. Everytime, I get this:

[image: Error]

My entity is declared like this:

```
public class Serie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$")]
    [Range(0, 9999999999999999.99)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Season> Seasons { get; set; }
    public List<Rental> Rentals { get; set; }
    public List<Assessment> Assessments { get; set; }

}
```

On my razor page I have this on html side:

```
@page
@model Shows4All.Pages.Series.CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Serie</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Serie.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Serie.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Serie.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Serie.Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="number" asp-for="Serie.Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Serie.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Serie.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Serie.Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Serie.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

I already tried without Data annotation and withou type="number" on html side...but it doesn't work. Any idea how can it be solved?

Comment: This is likely an issue with the default locale being used. Try `12,45` (use comma instead of dot).

Comment: @Leandro I already tried that. Does not work :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [double and decimal not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423127/double-and-decimal-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add locale configuration in your aspet.config file like this:

```
  <configuration> 
      <system.web>
          <globalization culture ="en-US" />
      </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

If didn't work, try remove the Regex attribute and test it again.